# AjaxOptions OnSuccess callback with parameter not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to use AjaxOptions.OnSuccess to call a javascript function and pass a parameter to it.  I am able to call a basic function with no parameters without a problem, it's just the parameter passing.

Here is my JS function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeRow (itemId) {

        alert(itemId);
    }
</script>
```

And my AjaxOptions declaration in razor:

```
New AjaxOptions With {.OnSuccess = "function(){removeRow(" + item.Id.ToString + ");}"}
```

On the client side the link appears like this:

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-success="function(){removeRow(3);}" href=...
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
New AjaxOptions With {.OnSuccess = String.Format("removeRow({0})", item.Id) }
```

Comment: Thanks gram!  I tried so many variations on that theme, but all of the answers I found on google said I needed to format my call differently.  This worked perfectly.